# Distance formula using initial velocity and acceleration

Tags: acceleration, velocity, distance

We know $S=ut+1/2at^2$.
Now, let's say my initial velocity is $u=10\text { m/s}$ and acceleration $a=5\text{ m/s}^2$.

In first second distance traveled $S^{t=1}=10\text { m}$ as my speed is $10\text{ m/s}$ and time is $1 \text{ s}$.

In next second my speed will be $15m/s$ as $a=5m/s^2$and distance travelled will be $S^{_t=2}=S^{_t=1} + 15=25m$ as distance traveled in 2nd second is $15m$.

Now when I apply the same case in equation $S=ut+1/2at^2$ where $u=10m/s$, $a=5m/s^2$ and $t=2s$ I get $S=30m$

Where Iam I getting wrong?

Comment: Suppose you're travelling at a *constant* speed of 10 m/s, then after the first second you travel a distance of 10 m. Right. But if you're *accelerating* then during that first second your speed will increase above 10 m/s and therefore you will travel *more* than 10 m.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Exchange. Note that we are not a homework help-site and check-my-work questions are generally off-topic. That said, the problem is that your first idea (first second/second second) doesn't take into account that the speed is NOT 10 m/2 for the whole second, but gradually increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first second, the distance you traveled is your mean velocity x 1s. That is: (10m/s + 15m/s)/2, so you travel 12.5m.

(*) uniform acceleration implies that Mean velocity = (initial velocity + final velocity)/2

In the next second, your mean velocity is (15m/s + 20m/s)/2, sou you travel 17.5m.

12.5m  + 17.5m = 30m